# Unable to access values while passing 2-D pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code :

```
int allocationMatrix[2+ 1][1+ 1];
    allocationMatrix[0][0] = 2;
    allocationMatrix[0][1] = 1;
    buildAllocationMatrix(flowNProcess, allocationMatrix);
```

The buildAllocationMatrix function is declared like:

```
void buildAllocationMatrix(FlowNProcess *flowNProcess, int *allocationMatrix)
```

inside it, if I check the value of `*(allocationMatrix+1)`, it gives 0 but the assignment
before calling the function is `allocationMatrix[0][1] = 1;` Not sure why its giving 0
It should return 1. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Doesn't the compiler complain about a type mismatch — between `int *` expected and `int (*)[2]` passed?  That should tell you you are doing things wrong — your compiler doesn't complain idly but only when it has spotted a bug in your code.

Comment: You really need to provide an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Answer (score 0):

- Pass `int **allocationMatrix`inside function since it is 2D array.

(because`int *allocationMatrix` is interpreted as passing address of 1D array) .

- And access it by
  `*(*(allocationMatrix+0)+1)`.

(Reason: by using`*(allocationMatrix+0)` you will get address of 0th row and in order to get address of 0th row 1st column we can use `(*(allocationMatrix+0)+1)` thus to get element of that position dereference it as
`*(*(allocationMatrix+0)+1)` ).

While accessing you can skip zero.